# How to fix Warning: `getFieldDecorator` will override `value`,so please don't set `value and v-model` directly and use `setFieldsValue` to set it.?

Tags: vue.js, antd

I'm coding a custom validation form component using ant-design-vue

I have changed my code nearly same as the example showed on the official website, but still got warning, the only difference is the example use template to define child component, but I use single vue file

```
//parent component
...some other code
<a-form-item
    label="account"
>
  <ReceiverAccount
      v-decorator="[
       'receiverAccount',
        {
          initialValue: step.receiverAccount,
          rules: [
           {
              required: true,
              message: 'need account',                      

           }
          ]
        }
      ]"
  />
</a-form-item>
...some other code
```

```
//child component
<template>
    <a-input-group compact>
        <a-select
            :value="type"
            @change="handleTypeChange"
        >
            <a-select-option value="alipay">alipay</a-select-option>
            <a-select-option value="bank">bank</a-select-option>
        </a-select>
        <a-input
            :value="number"
            @change="handleNumberChange"
        />
    </a-input-group>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        value: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => {}
        }
    },
    data() {
        const { type, number } = this.value
        return {
            type: type || 'alipay',
            number: number || ''
        }
    },
    watch: {
        value(val = {}) {
            this.type = val.type || 'alipay'
            this.number = val.number || ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        handleTypeChange(val) {
            this.triggerChange({ val })
        },
        handleNumberChange(e) {
            const number = parseInt(e.target.value || 0, 10)
            if (isNaN(number)) {
                return
            }
            this.triggerChange({ number })
        },
        triggerChange(changedValue) {
            this.$emit('change', Object.assign({}, this.$data, changedValue))
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I expect everything is fine, but the actual is I got **'Warning: `getFieldDecorator` will override `value`, so please don't set `value and v-model` directly and use `setFieldsValue` to set it.'**

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

because I am new of ant-design-vue, after one day research, solution is change :value to v-model and remove value props in the child component

```
<template>
    <a-input-group compact>
        <a-select
            v-model="type"
            @change="handleTypeChange"
        >
            <a-select-option value="alipay">alipay</a-select-option>
            <a-select-option value="bank">bank</a-select-option>
        </a-select>
        <a-input
            v-model="number"
            @change="handleNumberChange"
        />
    </a-input-group>
</template>
```